# Square of a zero random variable

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, bootstrap

Following up on this question and the answer:

[Bootstrap variance of squared sample mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26082/bootstrap-variance-of-squared-sample-mean)

Summary: $X_1$, ..., $X_n$ are IID. Define

$$
\overline{X}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i
$$

and $T_n=\overline{X}_n^2$. The rest of the question deals with computing bootstrap variance of $T_n$, for which one needs to compute $\mathbb{E}_{\hat{F}}T_n^2=\mathbb{E}_{\hat{F}}\overline{X}_n^4$.To simplify the calculations, the author defines

$$
S_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum(X_i-\overline{X}_n) = 0.
$$

AFAIU, $S_n\equiv0$ on every event. However, the answer proceeds computing $\mathbb{E}S_n^2$, $\mathbb{E}S_n^3$, and $\mathbb{E}S_n^4$ (but $\mathbb{E}S_n=0$).

So, it looks like I am not understanding the definition of $S_n$ or I am missing something about taking expectation. How is it possible that $S_n^2$ would be non-zero (to give non-zero $\mathbb{E}S_n^2$)?

Comment: A constant random variable is a special case of a random variable with moments, &tc., whose distribution is the point mass at its value. It is measurable wrt any $\sigma$ - algebra that contains this value.

Comment: $S_n^2$ is obviously equal to zero; but its expectation can also be calculated using formulas or theorems about random variables. So you have expectation = 0 on the one hand, and expectation = formula on the other hand. This gives you an equation: formula = 0. And this equation can help you prove stuff relating to $T_n$.

Comment: @Stef doesn't look like it. Look at $E(S_n^2)$. It must be zero. But it is also $\hat{a}_2/n > 0$, where $\hat{a}_2$ is an estimate of the second moment.

Comment: @Xi'an I understand that. The issue is how do you get $E(S_n^2)>0$ for $S_n\equiv 0$.

Comment: I think I got it. There is a bit of notation abuse there. Definition of $S_n$ should be $S_n^* = 1/n\sum(X_i^*-\overline{x}_n)$ where $X_i^*$ is RV from CDF $\hat{F}$ (which is fixed, once $X_i$'s are observed) and $\overline{x}_n = 1/n\sum x_i$ where $x_i$ is observed (and now fixed) value of $X_i$. Then $ES_n^* = 0$, but $S_n^*\neq0$.

Comment: This is a generic issue with link-dependent questions. Without reading the linked material the question does not makes complete sense.